# Set minimum length of a list?

Tags: python

I have a list in Python. I don't know exactly how long it is, but I know it's less than 15 items long.

I want to pad it out to exactly 15 items long, appending empty strings for all the items that I need to add.

Is there an efficient way to do this in Python?

I was hoping:

```
myarr = myarr[:15]
```

might work, but it doesn't.

Currently I have:

```
if len(myarr) < 15:
    for i in range(15 - len(myarr)):
        myarr.append('')
```

Any more compact suggestions?

Comment: you could write a custom class that acts like a list with padding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
myarr += [""] * (15 - len(myarr))
```

Comment: +1. This also doesn't need the test for `len(myarr) < 15` because the `*` repetition operator returns an empty list for a negative repetition count.

Comment: Perfect - compact and straightforward, just what I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, were strings mutable, why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @K3---rnc: It would kind of work with mutable strings, but probably have unintended side effects.  This append multiple copies of the same string object to the list, so modifying one of the string objects we assume to be mutable would modify all of them.

Answer (score 4):

in a oneliner way :

```
myarr.extend([""]* (15 - len(myarr)))
```

Answer (score 3):

To use pure slicing (no call to len):

```
padded = (source + [''] * MAX_LEN)[:MAX_LEN]
```

If this is called many times, then initialize an ALL_EMPTY list once at module scope. Then do:

```
padded = (source + ALL_EMPTY)[:MAX_LEN]
```